# Database & Application design to support Reporting, Analytics and Stats

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to determine the best way to structure my database (MS SQL) and web application (JAVA) so that we can provide lots of reports and aggregated results in close to real time. Think "Google Analytics".

Right now, we have a 12 million row table that records views and conversions and some other analytic data. This table is optimized for writes & updates (it has a limited set of indexes), but it is slow when querying for a date range and getting aggregated values.

We want to be able to have a dashboard showing (as close to) real time stats (as possible). But reading from that giant table is too slow to do on demand. Plus, we want to show a bunch of other aggregated and summaries information on this web app dashboard.

So, I am trying to figure out how I should set this up at the application and database level.

Which of these ideas sound good? What the pitfalls? Anybody have any suggestions that would help?

Ideas:

1. Run a background process, potentially on a dedicated server, that compiles and aggregates the analytics’ data  (from the 12 million plus row table) and populates a table with the aggregate data so that on the dashboard it can be basically read from this 'cache' table, and then the current day's or the last hour (or however long as elapsed since the last time stats were compiled) metrics would be added on.
2. Use log shipping to ship SQL Server log data to a partner server and do all the reporting on this secondary database so that the intensive reads do not affect the write/update performance (which must stay high to avoid noticeable delays on the site when pages are loaded etc)
3. Run a daily process to trim the rows in our 12 million+ row table, and move them to an archive table. I have tried doing this, but it slows down all of the write/updates on this table to a crawl. Is a partitioned table the answer here?

Do any of these sound like feasible solutions. Does anybody have any suggestions? Thank you for yor help!!

Answer (score 0):

Things I will suggest are server caching mechanics like memcached or anything like this to reduce the database requests. And save the calculated data. The next thing that can reduce the lags is a queue system with priority to do tasks if there is time and resources - this will be a "killer" for realtime. Another idea to search faster is to use search engines like elasticsearch, solr that can handle big data better. If you have a given number of calculates data per week/day/hour you can "cache" these for the past do you just have to do live for the current week/day/hour and archive the old ones in another table to keep history and be able to deliver single records. One important thing would be to know when the server has free resources to do hard tasks in this period and queue them in the work time. And the last idea is to make a second database that holds the real 12M+ rows and do the calculations and make a task that Imports the summaries into your real application database to reduce the write-lock lags.

I hope it will help you a bit - but for so much data and I think it will grow MySQL is without very custom optimization not the best solution. There are much faster and better data management and hold solutions like bigtable, elayticsearch/solr, cache based systems and do on.
Cache and Queue are the keywords I think.